# Deleting all files in folder on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

While trying to delete all the files in a folder for iOS, I've come to an error copying the code form another post on here. I've Googled around and couldn't find what #import I was missing or anything.

```
 NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSString *directory = [[self documentsDirectory]     stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Photos"];
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [fm removeItemAtPath:cacheImageDirectory error:&error];
if (!success || error) {
    // something went wrong
}
```

I'm getting the error: No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'documentDirectory'. Could someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error is quite self explanatory: `UIViewController` does not have `documentsDirectory` selector.

Comment: Copy the `documentsDirectory` method from wherever you copied the other code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite self explanatory: `UIViewController` does not have `documentsDirectory` selector. You should modify your codes to something like:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSArray *urls = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urls[0]];
NSString *directory = [url stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Photos"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this its working for me.

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Photos"] error:nil];

Hope this solve your problem.